# The curvature of the induced connection on the antidual bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, connections, chern-classes

Let $E\to M$ be a complex vector bundle over a (real, smooth) manifold and $\nabla$ a connection on $E\to M$ whose curvature is $R$. From Section 1.5 of "Differential Geometry of Complex Vector Bundles" by Shoshichi Kobayashi, if $\nabla^{E^*}$ is the induced connection on the dual bundle $E^*\to M$, then its curvature $R^{E^*}$ is given by $R^{E^*}=-R^t$. On the other hand, if $\nabla^{\bar{E}}$ is the induced connection on the conjugate bundle $\bar{E}\to M$, then its curvature $R^{\bar{E}}$ is given by $R^{\bar{E}}=\bar{R}$.

My questions are

1. if $\nabla^{\overline{E^*}}$ is the induced connection on the antidual bundle (or called conjugate dual bundle) $\overline{E^*}\to M$, is the curvature $R^{\overline{E^*}}=-\bar{R}^t$?
2. If (1) is correct, then the Chern character form of $\nabla^{\overline{E^*}}$ should be $\textrm{ch}(\nabla^{\overline{E^*}})=\overline{\textrm{ch}(\nabla)}$?